# Generating a file based on build parameters with Jenkins

Tags: templates, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to generate an XML file that I will feed into a deployment tool once a build is complete. The template of the XML file is like this:

```
<Settings>
    <Version>${BUILD_NUMBER}</Version>
    ..
</Settings>
```

The template exists within my project (a .NET solution), and is used to deploy the project as a click once application. I'm trying to figure out how I'd get Jenkins to push the build number into a template file, so then I can feed it to the application using a command line Exec task.

Do any plugins exist that are capable of generating files from templates? What other avenues can I use to accomplish this task?

Comment: You need a file search-n-replace command line. Can't tell you much more till you indicate what environment you are on. Even Ant can be used to replace tokens

Comment: @Slav I was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to a command line exec task. I've got the master setup on Windows (2 builders) and a slave on RHEL (also with 2 builders). I'm using the MSBuild plugin with a custom msbuild file to build the project. Is there anything more you'd want to know about the environment?

Comment: It looks like I can use the FileUpdate task from the MSBuild Community Tasks package which I already have installed.

Answer (score 3):

I found that Jinja2 works nicely for this. It has some powerful filters but can also handle basic templates. Incidentally, Jinja2 is the templating mechanism used by Ansible.

To install Jinja2 (assuming you have some python 2.6+ tools available):

```
pip install Jinja2
```

or

```
easy_install Jinja2
```

From [this post](http://pythonwise.blogspot.com/2013/07/command-line-front-end-to-jinja2.html), you can get a command line wrapper for the Jinja2 library which I show simply below:

```
curl -LO https://bitbucket.org/tebeka/pythonwise/raw/31769f04bac832f8d781827f55ad6cc4d4ef3c07/jj2.py
chmod u+x jj2.py
```

Then you setup your jinja template file (let's call it build-descriptor.j2):

```
<Settings>
    <Version>{{BUILD_NUMBER}}</Version>
    ..
</Settings>
```

and use this in your Jenkins job:

```
jj2.py -v BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER} build-descriptor.j2 > build-info.xml
```